# "Flatten" CSS to HTML

Tags: css

What tools are available that will programatically merge an CSS stylesheet with an HTML document? With this I mean that style attributes are created on elements that match the CSS declarations.

Comment: It wouldn't be able to do it 1:1, for example, pseudo classes and the like.

Comment: you want to do it programatically or just one time?

Comment: Gah! Why would you want to do this? This is pretty much the opposite of good practices.

Comment: It's pretty much essential to do this for html email, actually considered best practice. If email clients would support standards then it would be a different story.

Comment: It's exactly for the purpose of HTML email.

Comment: I found this question, because flattening the css would make it easier to see what is applied. Such a tool could be useful.

Comment: @bigmattyh If you want to take a webpage and email it out, to get it to display correctly in Outlook you need to have the styles attached to each html tag. No other way. Even with the latest version of Outlook...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/) will do this along with a couple of other tweaks for html email. There are other tools around formatting for html email which can help too, can't think of the others but Premailer works great.

Comment: Yeah the guys over at Mailchimp also offer a similar service

Comment: As do Campaign Monitor, but they're not external tools.

Comment: They're not, but since c0dem4gnetic asked that question I felt it was safe to assume he wasn't aware of all the solutions readily available for HTML email, sometimes free too.

Comment: Yea definitely. I didn't mean to suggest that there was anything wrong with them, just thought that it was relevant to point out that these solutions sort of tie you into these services.